# how to get alias name on fetching the data from mongoDB using find query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, sails.js

I am using MongoDB, my table(table name "My_Table") looks like

```
attributes: {
        user_id: {
            type: 'string'
        }}
```

I like to get field name `user_id` as `user` as alias name

I able to get the value for My_Table using find query `My_Table.find({}).then(function(data){console.log(data)})`
using this query i can get the output as `{user_id: "11111"}`
but my expected output with alias name as `{user : "11111"}`

for this I don't know whether I need to get add some field in attributes or need to change my find method.

anyone please help to get through this issue, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
My_Table.aggregate([
{$match:{}},
{$project:{user:"$user_id",id:1}}
])
```

In $project or $addFields stage you can format your output whatever you want

Comment: Your code may be correct but please add some explanation also.

Comment: I am having JSON as  [{user_id: 123, id : 01
}, {user_id : 456, id: 02}]. when I use this code My_Table.aggregate([
{$match:{}},
{$project:{_id:0, id:"$attributes.user_id"}}
]) it gives the empty response  as [ {}, {} ]

Comment: I have updated my answer  but u already has id field in document?

Comment: sorry, may i able to get user_id as user, it is also not possible as now